# Using the definite article the before night

Tags: articles

In the sentence given below

> [Other forms of harassment that plumbed new depths included ringing the doorbells of diplomats at late hours of ***the night*** to intimidate them, and even tailing cars ferrying diplomats’ children from school.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/low-tactics/article27473296.ece)

Why is **the** used before **night**.

Answer (score 1):

"Late hours of the night" is slightly idiomatic but fully correct.

It's normal to use 'the' when describing a time of day.

> I will visit you in the afternoon.
>
> I was woken every day early in the morning

Comment: What if plural of night, i.e., nights,  is used? Is the article still needed?

Comment: If you replaced "night" with "nights" then the sentence would be wrong, whether you used *the* or not.

Comment: Thanks @DJClayworth. When I asked the question what  I had in my mind was a sentence such as  "Late hours of nights of December are very cold in this region."
Is the sentence in double quotes not correct, except for the usage of article before "nights"?